# How to style OS VectorMap district data?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, vector, cartography, style, ordnance-survey

Following a [question about ways to load OS VectorMap data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/764/ways-to-load-os-vectormap-data), I have imported the data into ArcGIS, but now want to style it in a OS-map style. I have searched around, and found various bits of information, but no style files to download, or instructions on using them within ArcGIS.

I've tried doing some styling manually, but the results aren't good. Is there any way to get some of the official OS styles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tip load in a .lyr file, [will show red exclamation mark] right click and load in any polygon file. The layer will show the legend and symbology.
You will need to go through the os mastermap layers and extract features and styles you want to style in vectormap, some codes will be different, you can create two feature codes with a common tag (ID, osmmCODE,vectCode, Feature CODE) this can be joined to use symbology of MasterMap with Vectormap.

Though with a minute of research a **SOLUTION** :
If you want you can sign up to SnowFlake and get the VectorMap .lyr

Snowflake Go/loader OS VectorMap package contains:

- OSVectorMap.glp: GO Loader project file
- VectorMapFanOutDefinitions.xml: FanOut definitions for GO Loader
- CleanPolygonData.sql: SQL script that cleans polygon data
- registerArcSDE.bat: Batch script that registers the VectorMap layers in ArcSDE.
  **- *.lyr: ESRI ArcGIS Layer files that can be used in ArcGIS. There are Layerfiles for the LandPlan Style and Style1.**
- README.TXT 
  http://blogs.snowflakesoftware.com/techies/2010/03/new-os-vectormap-resource-available.htm

Had to add another answer as the 'add comment' is limited in  number characters

Answer (score 2):

Go to: MyESRI and login (or register then sign in)
http://www.myesriuk.com/esriuk/members/resourcecentre/downloads.asp

Go to: Trials and Free Software
select either
 ProductivitySuite2.0 (25/11/2009 10:54:12)
or
 ProductivitySuite2.1 Beta - ArcGIS 10 compatible  (29/07/2010 17:25:51)

scroll to the bottom and click 'Symbology Files'
Symbology.zip will have the OS MaterMap.Style and in subfolders various layer (.lyr) files
Don't forget the all important esri_121.ttf ~(truetype font) which has all the symbols the the Ordnance Survey have for ArcGIS.
Yes not perfect as is designed for OS MasterMap not OS VectorMap but will give you a good set of symbology for VectorMap Ditrict or VectorMap Open.

http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/oswebsite/products/vectormap/district/techinfo.html
might a helpful source for legend and OS feature codes

Hope that helps - suggest you create your own .style and .lyr files rather than those (make copies)
Note: if you send .mxd's to other computers you WILL require to send the .lyr,.style and that esri_121.ttf to avoid issues with the display and printing exporting to PDF etc.

Comment: Thanks. I have got the MasterMap symbols imported properly through using the Style file, but I can't seem to get the layer files to work properly with the VectorMap data. Is this possible? I've followed the instructions carefully, but I end up with all of my features coming out the same!

Answer (score 1):

The official VectorMap styles are on the [sample data page](https://www.ordnancesurveyvectormap.com/downloadSampleData/) in VML style rules ([zip](https://www.ordnancesurveyvectormap.com/a/dld/VML_Data_Stylesheets.zip)), and detailed in the user guide ([PDF](https://www.ordnancesurveyvectormap.com/a/pdf/userGuide.pdf)). You could manually convert these into proprietary ArcGIS .lyr files, unfortunately there is no adopted interchange format for styles. There's also a [commercial tool](http://www.snowflakesoftware.com/products/goloader/) which claims to do the conversion directly.

Answer (score 1):

Ordnance Survey have now released stylesheets as open data https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/resources/carto-design/cartographic-stylesheets.html

Files are on github https://github.com/OrdnanceSurvey/OS-VectorMap-District-stylesheets